# Text-To-Speech to read websites in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility, text-to-speech

I am using the Chrome browser and I know OS X has built-in voice synthesis that can speak to assist visually impaired users.

Can I use this feature to have the computer read contents of websites for me? Eg., I'd like to select a couple of paragraphs and have them read.

I know Safari has that built-in, but for one, there I don't know how to change the voice (e.g. I'd prefer a male voice), and secondly, I'd prefer to have it with Chrome.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

OS X's built in screen reader, [VoiceOver](http://www.apple.com/accessibility/voiceover/), works in Chrome.

To enable it, go to System Preferences-> Universal Access-> Seeing and toggle the VoiceOver: radio group to On. You will also be able to check the shortcut key for easily enabing/disabling VoiceOver.

I recommend you take some time and familiarize yourself with VoiceOver; it's very powerful but takes some getting used to.

Click the VoiceOver Utility button to configure VoiceOver. This lets you change, among many other options, the voice and speaking speed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Chrome supports macOS built-in text-to-speech functionality.
Select the text in the browser then use any of these options:

- `Right-click` -> `Speech` -> `Start Speaking`
- `Edit` menu -> `Speech` -> `Start Speaking`

You can also assign a global keyboard shortcut that will apply across multiple applications:

1. `System Settings` -> `Keyboard` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts...` -> `App Shortcuts` -> click the `+` button to add a new shortcut
2. **Application**: `All Applications` (or only `Google Chrome.app` if you prefer)
3. **Menu Title**: `Start Speaking`
4. **Keyboard Shortcut**: Assign the the keyboard shortcut of your choice
5. *Optionally*: repeat the above step for `Stop Speaking`

Comment: Isn't this the standard macOS text-to-speech which is available in all/most applications?

Comment: Safari has exactly the same menu entry/context menu, and uses the same voice. It's not enabled automatically in all applications (i.e. Firefox doesn't have it), but IMHO it's the built-in functionality. Nevertheless, great for Chrome to have it as well.

Comment: Thanks @nohillside, I've updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

Fortunately, someone (me) developed a Chrome extension that does exactly what you're looking for: [Announcify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mmiolkcfamcbpoandjpnefiegkcpeoan)

PS: Sorry for shamelessly advertising my own products.